# Rails after_find callback ignore query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

So, I call method `Article.getByTag()`.

Callback after_find work, but ignore query (in which get all tags by current article).

It's rails log

```
Started GET "/article/lorem" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-22 08:51:11 +0400
Processing by ArticleController#show_tag as HTML
  Parameters: {"tagname"=>"lorem"}
  Tags Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`name` = 'lorem' LIMIT 1
  Article Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` INNER JOIN `tag2articles` ON `tag2articles`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id` WHERE `tag2articles`.`Tags_id` = 5
start set article tags for article 3
getTags by article 3
end set article tags
```

Article class:

```
    class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :text, :title
  attr_accessor :tags    

  has_many :tag2articles


  after_find do |article|
        logger.info 'start set article tags for article '+article.id.to_s
        article.tags = Tag2article.getTags(article.id)
        logger.info 'end set article tags'
  end

  def self.getByTag(tagname)
    @tag = Tags.get(tagname)
    Article.joins(:tag2articles).where('tag2articles.Tags_id' => @tag[:id]).all()
  end

end
```

and class Tag2article

```
class Tag2article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Article
  belongs_to :Tags
  attr_accessible :Article, :Tags

  def self.getTags(article)
    logger.info 'getTags by article '+article.to_s
    @tags = Tag2article.joins(:Tags).where(:Article_id => article).select('tags.*')
    return @tags
  end

  def self.getArticle(tag)
    Tag2article.where(:Tags_id => tag).joins(:Article).select('articles.*')
  end
end
```

Comment: Where is the `Tag` model class? How is it implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, this is all you need:

Article class:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags_to_articles
  has_many :tags, through: :tags_to_articles 
end
```

and the model class for the join table

```
class TagsToArticle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

and you fetch all articles by tag name by doing:

```
Article.joins(:tags).where('tags.name' => tag_name)
```

I'm writing this from my head and I have **NO** idea what you managed to implement in your code so far, so please excuse me if the code doesn't work from the start - play with it and *make* it work.

Also, I suggest starting a new tutorial project, you reinvented so many wheels there (notice that you don't need an `after_find` hook because `has_many :tags, through: :tags_to_articles` does this for you) and did so many funny stuff (like naming attributes of a class the same name as the class it references) that you'll just burn yourself in frustration.

Also, if you use rails 4 you don't need to do attr_accessible dance, and if you don't I suggest taking a look at `strong_parameters` gem https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

AND TAKE SPECIAL NOTE OF NAMING CONVENTIONS - singular and plural, camelcase and hungarian notation, uppercase and lowercase, they all have their place and their meaning and the tutorials usually make a good job of taking you through it

Ruby and Rails are quite beautiful and powerful, but only if you let them. There's no benefit inherent in the language that will somehow infuse your code if you're still essentially writing Java.

Comment: Thank's for you detailed answer! . until this moment doesnt know about :through.  I'm begginer, thank's for your  notes by my code

Comment: @NikitaHarlov, np :) A rule of thumb while doing the basic tutorial stuff is "if it looks the least bit complicated to implement, there's almost certainly an inbuilt way to do it" :) and welcome to rails